# Add dictionary values stored in variable to the list python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am new to python. I want to add the dictionary (keys and values) to the list continuously. The list already contains some dictionary values. It should be added next to it.
Any suggestions please...

Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

fields = {'a': 'steven', 'b': 'kumar'}
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
ip ='192.168.1.1'

result = [((timestamp, {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up', fields})]
print (result)
```

Required Output:

```
[((February 19 2019, 13:18:53, {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up', 'a':'steven','b':'kumar})]
```

Comment: The required output you have stated is not clear. You have tuple inside of the list. Is it by mistake or you want it like that? It should be: [timestamp, {key1:val1, key2:val2}]

Comment: In ur required output there are unmatched brackets. Also it would be better if you can include more sample dicts to the required output list so that people can understand ur problem statement better.

Comment: did you try result.append()? To append new items to the existing list. If this is not what you are looking for, please elaborate your question.

Comment: I tried that..append() will add and create a new one at the end. I want that inside the { } braces. Finally i got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unpacking:

```
result = [((timestamp, {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up', **fields}))]
```

Also, you were missing a closing parentheses in `result`; I added it in. If you meant to have only 1 set of parentheses, remove one parenthesis at the front and at the back.

You can read more about this feature [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack your `fields`:

```
from datetime import datetime

fields = {'a': 'steven', 'b': 'kumar'}
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
ip ='192.168.1.1'
result = [(timestamp, {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up', **fields})]
print (result)
[('February 19 2019, 16:57:22', {'monitor.ip': '192.168.1.1', 'b': 'kumar', 'a': 'steven', 'monitor.status': 'up'})]
```

BTW, original code `result=...` had a `SyntaxError` with redundant `(`, which is removed in answer.

To make sure, `unpacking` was introduced in python 3.5. In case of python 3.4 or lower, this will raise a `SyntaxError` and thus have to use different approaches such as `dict.update`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Kindly upvote this question if you feel it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
my_dict = {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up'}
my_dict.update(fields)
result = [(timestamp, my_dict)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from datetime import datetime

fields = {'a': 'steven', 'b': 'kumar'}
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
ip ='192.168.1.1'

fields.update({'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up'})
result = [timestamp, fields]
print (result)
```

Comment: output of this code is different than what OP wants

Comment: `dict.update` is an in-place operation which returns `None`

Comment: @prashant rana Yes but I thought that was an mistake as Shivam Pandya pointed out in a comment on the question

Comment: @GiladShnoor `.update(fields)` using this resulting none in the output , which is not as desired by OP. Check again what `.update()` is doing

Comment: @GiladShnoor great

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

fields = {'a': 'steven', 'b': 'kumar'}
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
ip ='192.168.1.1'
new_dic = {'monitor.ip': ip, 'monitor.status': 'up'}
new_dic.update(fields)

result = [((timestamp, new_dic))]
print (result)

# output
# [('February 19 2019, 13:30:50', {'monitor.ip': '192.168.1.1', 'monitor.status': 'up', 'a': 'steven', 'b': 'kumar'})]
```